# Any way to make Android Studio and IntellIJ share Maven indicies?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

So I have both IntelliJ 14 and Android Studio installed on my system. I use and need them both. The thing is they love wasting disk space:

```
PS C:\Users\Nilzor\.IntelliJIdea14\system\Maven\Indices> du

Name   Sum (MB)         Sum
----   --------         ---
Index1 1 197,818 1256003142
Index0 1,460        1531310
Index3 0,120         125768
Index2 0,120         125389
Index6 0,118         123522
Index4 0,118         123519
Index5 0,118         123482

PS C:\Users\Nilzor\.AndroidStudio\system\Maven\Indices> du

Name   Sum (MB)         Sum
----   --------         ---
Index2 1 531,201 1605580942
Index0 2,016        2113926
Index1 0,030          31129
Index3 0,030          31118
```

When I look at `index.properties` in Index1 and Index2 respectively, they both naturally point to `http\://repo1.maven.org/maven2`

I don't want 1 GB of indexing of the central maven repository duplicated on my precious SSD disk. Any way to avoid it, and make Android Studio cooperate with IntelliJ on indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use JCenter instead of mavenCentral, it won't index it, and you can delete the index files (though they'll be rebuilt any time you open a project that uses them).

If you want them to share the index, you could try symlinking the files to each other, though that could get exciting if you run both IJ and Android Studio at the same time.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why JCenter doesn't need to be indexed? What's the difference?

Comment: It's because the code to index JCenter hasn't been written yet ;)

Comment: It's not because of that. It's because we believe downloading huge and rarely-updated index files to all the client machines is a very stupid idea nowadays. Our server hardware is good enough to serve real-time searches, we don't need to delegate the search to the clients.